# get_comments() returns empty array if called through AJAX

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, comments

I'm facing a quite strange issue with a simple get_comments() implementation in admin panel.
Code is this *(post ID is truly 1234)*

```
get_comments('post_id=1234&status=approve');
```

It returns proper results if called directly, but with AJAX implementation gives just an empty array, as if no comments are found.

Ajax usage is the normal one

```
function my_function() {}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function');
```

Anyone ever experienced something similar? 
thanks

---

Javascript usage

```
var data = {
    action: 'my_function',
};
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

AJAX/PHP part

```
function my_function() { 
    var_dump( get_comments('post_id=1234&status=approve') ); 
    die(); 
} 
add_action('wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function');
```

Comment: Post the full function or it is impossible to know what happens.

Comment: I already debugged parameters passed through AJAX, also reducing code to minimum: it doesn't work.

So: this doesn't work

`function my_function() {
   var_dump( get_comments('post_id=1234&status=approve') ); 
   die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function');`

Comment: Please, [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/174156/edit) and add the code there. Aslo, include the javascript part and describe the context where you are using it (front end or admin side, etc).

Comment: Done, as said it is implemented in admin side

Comment: I've tested your code and I get the comments for the specified post. Are you sure there are approved comments for your 1234 post?

Comment: Sure: executing `get_comments('post_id=1234&status=approve')` in a normal page I get the two post comments. Really don't know what could be involved with AJAX..!